# How to show global navigation from level2 instead of level1 using SharePoint AspMenu?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, navigation, dropdown

I have a site collection with 4 sites under one another.

site1
   site2
     site3
        site4

This is how my global navigation looks like.

[image]

But I want to show it like this i.e. I want to start from level2 which is site2.

[image]

I tried playing with **StaticDisplayLevels** and **MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels** values in AspMenu but no luck. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by choosing "Show current navigation...." (the last one) option in Navigation settings for current site instead of "Show parent navigation..."